# Swift Explicit vs. Inferred Typing : Performance

Tags: performance, types, compiler-construction, swift

I'm reading a tutorial about Swift (http://www.raywenderlich.com/74438/swift-tutorial-a-quick-start) and it preconized to not set type explicitly because it's more readable this way.

I do not really agree about this point but that's not the question. My question is : Is it more efficient, in terms of performance (compiler...) to set type explicitly ?

For example, would this : `var hello: Int = 56` be more efficient than this : `var tutorialTeam = 56`

Comment: Since its a compiler check, it won't affect performance of your app at all. `let a = 1` and `let a:Int = 1` are completely equivalent. If you inspect `a` by using alt+click, it will say its an `Int` type.

Comment: Won't the compiler check any type for 1 before it sets it as an Int ?

Comment: Um?  Perhaps you're not quite understanding the point of static type inference.  When you leave an annotation out, it doesn't mean that the compiler just treats the variable as some generic register value that it has to work around.  Type inference occurs first, the variable is then treated as though it were that type in all expressions it's used in.  If for some reason the compiler cannot deduce the type of the variable, it becomes a type error.  Nothing occurs at runtime.  There is no performance gain to be had.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, I've no "low level" language experience that's why ! You can make an answer and I'll mark my question as solved if you want.

Comment: @CodaFi second the suggestion you add that as an answer; the difference between compile and run time is not clear to lots of readers and you explain it very well.

Comment: @jrturton Meh, I think Dave Wood's analysis is enough.  Besides, I can't think of a way to reword the comment that wouldn't be bland and dense.

Comment: The article's advice on this point seems really bad. Making it clear what type a value has is going to make the code easier to read.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is **no difference in performance** between code that uses explicit types and code which uses type inference. The compiled output is identical in each case.

When you omit the type the compiler simply infers it.

The very small differences observed in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24589249/249933) are just your usual micro benchmarking artefacts, and cannot be trusted!

Whether or not you include the explicit type is a matter of taste. In some contexts it might make your code more readable.

The only time it makes a difference to your code is when you want to specify a different type to the one which the compiler would infer. As an example:

```
var num = 2
```

The above code infers that `num` is an `Int`, due to it being initialised with an integer literal. However you can 'force' it to be a `Double` as follows:

```
var num: Double = 2
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The compiled out is the same, so it's literally impossible for explicit or implicit types to make any difference in performance.

Comment: @PaulManta - thank you, it annoyed me to see the accepted answer being blatantly wrong!

Comment: Good idea to check the compiled output.

Comment: `Whether or not you include the explicit type is a matter of taste. In some contexts it might make your code more readable.`

Exactly! Adding type annotations "to improve compiler performance" will in the long run cause the code to be bloated and less readable. In the meantime, the compiler performance is improving because of the work of the Swift compiler engineers - which will render the added type annotations useless.

Answer (score 5):

From my experience, there's been a huge performance impact in terms of compilation speed when using explicit vs inferred types. A majority of my slow compiling code has been resolved by explicitly typing variables.

It seems like the Swift compiler still has room for improvement in this area. Try benchmarking some of your projects and you'll see a big difference.

Here's an article I wrote on [how to speed up slow Swift compile times](https://panupan.com/2016/02/16/how-to-speed-up-slow-swift-compile-times/) and how to find out what is causing it.

Answer (score -1):

Type inference will not affect performance in your given example. However, I did find that being specific about the Type in your Swift array does impact performance significantly.

For example, the method below shuffles an array of type `Any`.

```
class func shuffleAny(inout array: [Any]) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
        let currentObject: Any = array[i]
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random()) % array.count
        let randomObject: Any = array[randomIndex]

        array[i] = randomObject;
        array[randomIndex] = currentObject
    }
}
```

The above function is actually much slower than if I were to make this function take an array of `Int` instead like this

```
class func shuffleIntObjects(inout array: [Int]) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.count; i++) {
        let currentObject: Int = array[i]
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random()) % array.count
        let randomObject: Int = array[randomIndex]

        array[i] = randomObject;
        array[randomIndex] = currentObject
    }
}
```

The function that uses `[Any]` clocked in at 0.537 seconds 3% STDEV for 1 million `Int` objects. And the function that uses `[Int]` clocked in at 0.181 seconds 2% STDEV for 1 million Int objects.

You can check out this repo (https://github.com/vsco/swift-benchmarks) which details a lot more interesting benchmarks in Swift. One of my favorite ones is that Swift generics perform very poorly with the test conditions mentioned above