# How to access extension of UIColor in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, extension-methods, uicolor

I am trying to create a Swift extension of UIColor class as

```
extension UIColor {
    
    func getCustomBlueColor() -> UIColor {
        return UIColor(red:0.043, green:0.576, blue:0.588, alpha:1.00)   
    }

}
```

After this I accessed the method as

```
btnShare.setTitleColor(UIColor.getCustomBlueColor(**UIColor**), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

I don't know what I should pass as an argument to this statement.

Comment: you have to pass no arguments at all, just call `UIColor.getCustomBlueColor()`

Comment: @tkanzakic would it not need to be a `class func` to access it like that? - Users example would need to be accessed like `UIColor().getCustomBlueColor()`

Comment: yeah..wezly so i was figuring out how to access the instance type not class ones

Comment: [Swift Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43642790/1634890)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You have defined an *instance method*, which means that you can call
it only on an `UIColor` instance:

```
let col = UIColor().getCustomBlueColor()
// or in your case:
btnShare.setTitleColor(UIColor().getCustomBlueColor(), forState: .Normal)
```

The compiler error "missing argument" occurs because
[Instance Methods are Curried Functions in Swift](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/),
so it could equivalently be called as

```
let col = UIColor.getCustomBlueColor(UIColor())()
```

(But that would be a strange thing to do, and I have added it only to
explain where the error message comes from.)

---

But what you really want is a *type method* (`class func`)

```
extension UIColor{
    class func getCustomBlueColor() -> UIColor{
        return UIColor(red:0.043, green:0.576 ,blue:0.588 , alpha:1.00)
    }
}
```

which is called as

```
let col = UIColor.getCustomBlueColor()
// or in your case:
btnShare.setTitleColor(UIColor.getCustomBlueColor(), forState: .Normal)
```

without the need to create an `UIColor` instance first.

Comment: thanks martin it makes me clear now...but this statement doesnot compile right on xcode 6.3 let col = UIColor.getCustomBlueColor(UIColor())

Comment: @copeME: I do not have access to Xcode 6.3 currently, so I can check that only later. But I mentioned `let col = UIColor.getCustomBlueColor(UIColor())` only to explain the compiler error message, that is not what you should actually do. You really should define it as a type method with `class`.

Comment: yeah i was hitting trial on how to access when it was an instance methods..thanks martin

Comment: @copeME: You are right, there was an error in the "curried function example".

Answer (score 25):

With Swift 3, predefined UIColors are used accordingly:

```
var myColor: UIColor = .white // or .clear or whatever
```

Therefore, if you want something similar, such as the following...

```
var myColor: UIColor = .myCustomColor
```

...then, you would define the extension like so:

```
extension UIColor {

    public class var myCustomColor: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 248/255, green: 248/255, blue: 248/255, alpha: 1.0)
    }

}
```

In fact, Apple defines white as:

```
public class var white: UIColor
```

Comment: `var myColor = UIColor.myCustomColor` is far more appropriate FYI. You should always use type inference over explicit type casting. This is documented in numerous area's of the Swift book Apple has provided and has been considered best practice during WWDC keynotes.

Comment: TheCodingArt - that is your opinion, not a fact.  In fact, your down vote and comment are misleading, and frankly irresponsible.  The compiled output of using type inference vs. explicit type casting is identical.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588893/swift-explicit-vs-inferred-typing-performance   I, for one, prefer the readability of my code over what you have posted, but that too, like yours, is only an opinion.

Comment: What I stated was fact not opinion. An opinion is not formed from recommendations provided directly by Apple that are documented in numerous areas, but an assumption is made by assuming I'm the one who down voted you. If you would like to learn more regarding appropriate recommended Swift API and general usage guidelines, Apple has provided plenty of publicly available resources for reference. Would really recommend getting your facts straight and also checking up on Apple's guidelines rather following your personal preferred styles.

Comment: I have checked the guidelines, and cannot find any section where Apple states that one should always use type inference over explicit type casting.  Nor have I seen any article or explanation about why this is far more appropriate.  If it is a "best practice", then it is, by definition, an opinion, not a fact.  I just provided a link in my last comment whereby it shows that they both compile to the same output.  It would help if you provided a link to whatever it is you are citing.

Answer (score 23):

Swift 3, Swift 4, Swift 5:

```
extension UIColor {
   static let myBlue = UIColor(red:0.043, green:0.576 ,blue:0.588, alpha:1.00) 
}
```

Use:

```
btnShare.setTitleColor(.myBlue, for: .normal)
```

Or

```
self.view.backgroundColor = .myBlue
```

If you use Color Set in *.xcassets (iOS11+).
For example, you have a color with the name «appBlue». Then:

```
extension UIColor {

private static func getColorForName(_ colorName: String) -> UIColor {
    UIColor(named: colorName) ?? UIColor.red
}

static var appBlue: UIColor {
    self.getColorForName("appBlue")
}
}
```

Use:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = .appBlue
```

Answer (score 3):

Get this customized extension for `UIColor`

```
extension UIColor {
    // Method returns a custom color
    static func rgb(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
        return .init(red: red / 255, green: green / 255, blue: blue / 255, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question being asked.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change your statement like,

```
 btnShare.setTitleColor(UIColor().getCustomBlueColor(), forState:.Normal)
```

More detailed explanation is [here](https://youtu.be/ENs97dVN_uk).

Answer (score 1):

You defined a instance function. It means you need an instance of `UIColor` in case to use `getCustomBlueColor()`-method.

It looks like you want to have a class method, instead of the instance method. So you have to change your definition like this:

```
extension UIColor{
    class func getCustomBlueColor() -> UIColor{
        return UIColor(red:0.043, green:0.576 ,blue:0.588 , alpha:1.00)
    }
}
```

Note the 'class' before func, so the method is now accessible as a class method.

The same story using class methods in a structure:

```
struct MyColors{
    static func getCustomBlueColor() -> UIColor{
        return UIColor(red:0.043, green:0.576 ,blue:0.588 , alpha:1.00)
    }
}
let color = MyColors.getCustomBlueColor()
```

If you just want to have a class with some color definitions, I recommend you to use a struct over a class or extension:

```
struct MyColors{
    static var getCustomBlueColor = { return UIColor(red:0.043, green:0.576 ,blue:0.588 , alpha:1.00) }
}
let color = MyColors.getCustomBlueColor()
```

Comment: hi @Chuck. I have formatted your answer. Just have a look!

Comment: thanks :-) I am really new to stackoverflow, so sorry for making formatting mistakes

Answer (score 1):

Could use a computed property:

```
extension UIColor {
  var customBlueColor: UIColor {
    return UIColor(red:0.043, green:0.576 ,blue:0.588 , alpha:1.00)
  }
}
```

And then to call it:

```
UIColor().customBlueColor
```

Comment: It would be far better to make it a `static` property so you don't need to create a throwaway instance of `UIColor`.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift:**

```
extension UIColor {
    open class var yourOrange: UIColor {
        return UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 0.988, green: 0.337, blue: 0.063, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UIColor Extension **Swift 5**

```
extension UIColor {
    static var yourColor:UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 0.745, green: 0.157, blue: 0.074, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

---

**Use :**
view.backgroundColor = .yourColor

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers.