# Function call is requiring an argument but the function takes no arguments

Tags: swift

I have this code in a file called `makeRequest.swift` in a class `makeRequest`:

```
class makeRequest {
    func callAPI () {
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://APIServer.com)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
            println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        }

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

And I call it with `makeRequest.callAPI()`. However, it is requiring an argument:

> Missing argument for parameter #1 in call

When I tried to configure `callAPI` to take a string:

```
class makeRequest {
    func callAPI(urlEnd: String) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And call it with

```
makeRequest.callAPI("ending")
```

It errors with

> Cannot invoke 'callAPI' with an argument list type of '(String)'

Comment: BTW, you should follow Swift's naming conventions and names classes and other types starting with an upper-case letter. I missed the fact that makeRequest was a class because it starts with a lower case letter. Good thing Matt was paying more attention.

Comment: Quite similar problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648348/how-to-access-extension-of-uicolor-in-swift (including an explanation for the strange error message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about how confusing Swift's error messages are. (There is a cool reason for the nature of this error message, but never mind that right now.) The problem is really that you are calling this method as a class method but it is declared as an instance method.

Comment: Ok, now you've piqued my curiosity. What's the cool reason for this particular obtuse Swift error message?

Comment: Well, @DuncanC, I didn't want to tell the OP, because it would just confuse him. But he's not listening, so I'll tell you! :) I hope you're sitting down, because I'm about to rock your world. http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html Search for "The Secret Life of Instance Methods."

Comment: Gack. That's a little strange. I guess it makes sense. Weird, perverted sense.

Comment: What are the advantages of making it like that?