# Can you pass a typed array to a function within an enum in swift?

Tags: function, swift, enums, arguments

In a Swift app, I've created an enum with a function that takes an array of CLBeacon objects as it's only argument (i.e., `[CLBeacon]`).  I get no clang errors with the enum, however when I try to use the enum, clang complains that I can't invoke the function with an argument list of `([CLBeacon])`.  Here's the code:

```
enum BeaconArrayState {

    case NoObjectOnScreen, FirstObjectOnScreen, FirstObjectOffScreen

    mutating func check(beacons: [CLBeacon]) -> BeaconArrayState {

        switch self {

            case FirstObjectOnScreen:
                return .FirstObjectOnScreen
            case FirstObjectOffScreen:
                return .FirstObjectOffScreen
            case NoObjectOnScreen:
                if beacons.count > 0 {
                    println("push to screen associated with beacon \(beacons[0].minor)")
                }
                return .NoObjectOnScreen
        }
    }
}
var beaconArrayState: BeaconArrayState = .NoObjectOnScreen

func beaconManager(manager: AnyObject!, didRangeBeacons beacons: [AnyObject]!, inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!) {
    let knownBeacons = beacons.filter{$0.proximity != CLProximity.Unknown}
    //send updated beacons array to perform parseBeacons
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("updateNotificationPriorities", object: knownBeacons)

    beaconArrayState = BeaconArrayState.check(knownBeacons as [CLBeacon])
}
```

This gives: the error - `Cannot invoke 'check' with argument list of type '([CLBeacon])'`

The code in the case statements is irrelevant for now and not yet determined, but why the error on invocation?

Comment: Essentially the same error as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648348/how-to-access-extension-of-uicolor-in-swift or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248855/function-call-is-requiring-an-argument-but-the-function-takes-no-arguments. You have defined an *instance method* but call it like a *type method*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are calling check method statically while that function is not static at all. Also check function its not a mutating function so you dont need mutating keyword. To make this work make the follow change `beaconArrayState = beaconArrayState.check(knownBeacons as [CLBeacon])` or if you want check method to mutate itself then change it like this :

```
mutating func check(beacons: [CLBeacon]) {

    switch self {

    case FirstObjectOnScreen:
        self = .NoObjectOnScreen
    case FirstObjectOffScreen:
        self = .FirstObjectOffScreen
    case NoObjectOnScreen:
        if beacons.count > 0 {
            println("push to screen associated with beacon \(beacons[0].minor)")
        }
        self = .NoObjectOnScreen
    }
}
```

then just call `beaconArrayState.check(knownBeacons as [CLBeacon])` and becaonArrayState will get its new value

Comment: Yes, thanks to you and Martin R.  I know I tried calling it as an instance method but still got the same error.  This time however, calling it as an instance method did indeed work.  Have you noticed that Clang can be very weird in updating its error messages with Swift sometimes?  I used "mutating" because I intend to change the state inside check() as I continue to complete the function.