# Swift Explicit vs. Inferred Typing : Memory Efficiency

Tags: swift, memory

Is it any difference in memory efficiency between these two declarations?

1: `var index: Int`
2: `var index = 0`

The reason is that I´m building a larger application and I´m looking of aspects of how to save memory. So is there any difference in the memory efficiency?

Comment: Strictly spoken this is an apples and peaches comparison because the first example only declares the variable and the second declares and initializes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no difference. The compiler will automatically infer the type of the second variable to be an Int. The compiler will also check for unassigned variables (like the first case) at compile time, not at runtime. So there is absolutely no difference.

Comment: I have the same answer with @Palle, In addition, you can refer to here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588893/swift-explicit-vs-inferred-typing-performance/28164341